# opencv cli app crashes on windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, visual-studio-2013, video-capture

I'm working on a visual studio project(CLI app) that does some image processing over frames captured using opencv's videocapture class.

The project works fine on my Windows 7 computer, but when I try to deploy it on Windows 10 the program crashes and the following is being thrown to the output:

```
0x0B37A1C9 (0x0E5C9020 0x0E94E880 0x0E65F020 0x00000500), DllGetClassObject() + 0x4D8B9 bytes(s)
0x0B2D2299 (0x00000280 0x0E94E880 0x00000018 0x00000500)
0x0B30C409 (0x0EA30000 0x00000280 0xFFFFFE20 0x00000500)
```

Any ideas as to where's it coming from? I'm not even sure that opencv is causing it..

This is the code that handles capturing the frame(from inside a loop):

```
    cv::Mat mIn;
    int camW = 640;
    int camH = 480;
    int w, h, nc, nI;
    size_t nbytesI, numberOfValues, sizeOfBuffers, sizeOfBuffersO;
    float *h_in;
    cv::VideoCapture camera;


    while (!g_quit)
    {
        reload_parameters(&demo, &oclobjects);
        g_paramsChanged = false;

        if (g_camera)
        {
            if (!g_cameraOpen)
            {
                camera.open(0); // open the default camera
                if (!camera.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
                {
                    cerr << "Couldn't open camera" << endl;
                    return -1;
                }
                camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, camW);
                camera.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, camH);
                g_cameraOpen = true;
            }
            // read in first frame to get the dimensions
            while (true)
            {
                camera >> mIn;
                if (!mIn.empty()) break;
            }
        }
...
```

I am using opencv 3.0.0 and visual studio 2013.

I would also be very happy simply for pointers as to what does this output mean.